# Find n permutations of a list of length p python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

So I have an array of about 40 items and need to find n permutations of the list. I know I can use itertools.permutations but that would give me all 40! different orderings which would take longer.

Is there a way I can create exactly n permutations of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.permutations` gives you an iterator over the permutations of your list. You can pull out values one by one, the function does not precompute anything.

If you just want the first `n` permutations that are produced without any further constraints, `islice` the result of `permutations`.

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, islice
>>> perms = islice(permutations(yourlist), n)
```

Computing of permutations will only start once you iterate over `perms` - either directly with a `for` loop or by making a container (`list`, `tuple`, `set`, ...) out of it.